# Error message "Some of the products are disabled" on checkout

Tags: checkout, quantity, magento2.4.4

I am facing a very strange error message on checkout level on our Magento 2.4.4 instance with **products with quantity below 1** and this only for customer group "Not logged in"

When **checking out** only an article with 0.5 units I get an **error message saying "Some of the products are disabled"**

[image: Error message: Some of the products are disabled]

But those products are all enabled in all our store views.

For those products o.5 is the minimum quantity, as they are a material, which can be bought in units < 1 and also in decimal quantities.

In our store I have the MOQ set as 0.5 globally for each customer group and then Quantity uses decimals = Yes

[image: MOQ 0.5]

**I can put the article with 0.5 into the shopping cart** without problem.

**But when I say "Proceed to checkout" with only 1 article with 0.5 int the cart, I get the error message as stated above.**

Strangely when I put 2 articles with 0.5 into the cart, I can checkout without any problem.

Only quantity below 1 creates a problem.

Does anyone know how and where this error message can stem from, even if the products are enabled?

Comment: may be you have set wrong value in Enable Qty Increments and  Qty Increments textbox.

Comment: may be it is magento2.4.4 bug.

compare  Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement ::savePaymentInformation function with old magento version.

Comment: just remove (int) from   if (!(int)$quote->getItemsQty()) { Line num: 179

it should be if (!($quote->getItemsQty())) {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your magento file **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php**

the **GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php** file is updated in magento2.4.4 version.

Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformation()

replace below code and check.

```
 if (!(int)$quote->getItemsQty()) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Some of the products are disabled.'));
        }
```

to

```
if(!$quote->getItemsQty())
        {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Some of the products are disabled.'));    
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately all values in Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart , Qty Uses Decimals, Enable Qty Increment set correct.

Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart = Use config settings as above
Qty uses decimals = Yes
Enable quantity Increments = No

Things is, that it works with logged in users but not with user group = Not logged in

Comment: do you get same issue for all products or only specified products?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Genius! This worked smooth like a knife through soft Amul butter :) Amazing. 

Additonal question: can it be that this already also needs to be changed when putting item to cart? Because there already we got a similar error message. When we double clicked that worked.

Comment: which message do you get when added product to cart?

Is it same message?

Comment: Hi. It sometimes said: "Please select a valid value. The two
nearest valid values are 0 and 1."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136272/discussion-between-s-p-and-ben).