# Magento 2.4 override core php file GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php

Tags: magento2.4.5

I want to override vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php. I made a di.xml in app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/etc/ like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement" type="Jilco\Qtybug\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

And the GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php in /home/jilco/public_html/app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/Model/

Also dit the deployement steps

```
rm -rf generated/code/*
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But the file is not replaced, what is wrong?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: The error (in the file) is stil there. When i replace directly in the core file the error is gone

Comment: Which method you are trying to override? Please add your code in app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php to your post, I'll help.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355647/error-message-some-of-the-products-are-disabled-on-checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jilco_Qtybug" />
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Jilco_Qtybug', __DIR__);
```

Create **app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement" type="Jilco\Qtybug\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Jilco/Qtybug/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php**

```
<?php

namespace Jilco\Qtybug\Model;


use Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentProcessingRateLimiterInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentSavingRateLimiterInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestBillingAddressManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestPaymentMethodManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;

class GuestPaymentInformationManagement extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement
{
    public function __construct(
        GuestBillingAddressManagementInterface $billingAddressManagement,
        GuestPaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement,
        GuestCartManagementInterface $cartManagement,
        PaymentInformationManagementInterface $paymentInformationManagement,
        QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
        ?PaymentProcessingRateLimiterInterface $paymentsRateLimiter = null,
        ?PaymentSavingRateLimiterInterface $savingRateLimiter = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $billingAddressManagement,
            $paymentMethodManagement,
            $cartManagement,
            $paymentInformationManagement,
            $quoteIdMaskFactory,
            $cartRepository,
            $paymentsRateLimiter,
            $savingRateLimiter
        );
    }

    // Add your override methods and your own methods here
}
```

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**